# Unable to mount NFS share

Tags: linux, debian, nfs, export

I have 3 servers :
Server1 : Stores my data. Had a exported folder. Debian 7 - Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 on x86_64
Server2 : "Client" where is the Server1 exported folder is mounted. Debian 7 -  Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 on x86_64
Server3 : Another "Client" on wich I'd like to mount the same Server1 exported folder. Debian 8 - Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 on x86_64.

I'm unable to mount the NFS share on Server3 using this command :

```
mount -t nfs Server1:/home/exported_folder /home/folder -v
```

Here's the command result :

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Jun 25 11:18:57 2015  
mount.nfs: trying text-based  options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.xxx.xxx,clientaddr=192.168.xxx.xxx'  
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied  
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting Server1:/home/folder
```

I used this command to mount the folder on Server2 and my Server2 fstab looks like this :

```
Server1:/home/folder   /home/folder nfs     nfsvers=3,rw    0       0
```

Server1 exports looks like this :

```
/home/folder (no_root_squash,rw)
```

What missed I ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Server2 is successfully accessing the share using NFSv3.
Server3 is failing to access the share using NFSv4.

Why don't you try using the same nfs options on server3 (nfsvers=3,rw) and see if anything changes?

Comment: I still use NFSv3, never NFSv4 :/

Comment: What i meant to say, was that your mount command on Server3 is *not* using nfsv3. The second line of your output says as much. Try forcing it with "-o vers=3" in your command.